# Executing gcloud commands within Terraform

Tags: terraform, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp

I've just gotten started with GCP provisioning using Terraform. I want to executing gcloud commands within Terraform eg. creating **compute instance group**.

I found on Terraform Registry site module - [[https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/gcloud/google/latest]](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/gcloud/google/latest).
When I wrote simple script test and provision this example using "terraform plan" -> I got error like:

```
 Error: External Program Execution Failed
│
│   with module.gcloud.data.external.env_override[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/gcloud/main.tf line 73, in data "external" "env_override":
│   73:   program = ["${path.module}/scripts/check_env.sh"]
│
│ The data source received an unexpected error while attempting to execute the program.
│
│ Program: .terraform/modules/gcloud/scripts/check_env.sh
│ Error: fork/exec .terraform/modules/gcloud/scripts/check_env.sh: no such file or directory
```

My code is:

```
module "gcloud" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/gcloud/google"
  version = "3.1.2"

  platform = "linux"
  additional_components = ["kubectl", "beta"] 

  create_cmd_entrypoint  = "gcloud"
  create_cmd_body        = "compute instance-groups managed --project=${var.project}"
  
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can't you just use the terraform ressource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_group

Answer (score 0):

There is rarely a case where using gcloud as part of terraform code is recommended, it defeats the whole purpose of declarative IaC programming.

I suggest you take a look at the [managed instance group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_group_manager) and [instance template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_template) resource types.